# Select dependent on Radio Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I make a `<SELECT>` visible if a particular `<INPUT type="radio">` is selected?

I have the following function at the end of `<BODY>`:

```
<script>
$('[data-dependent]').each(function () {
    var $ele = $(this);
    var dependsOn = $ele.data('dependent');
    $.each(dependsOn, function (target, value) {
        $(target).on('change', function () {
            if($(this).val() === value) {
                $ele.show();
            }
            else {
                $ele.hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

My HTML is:

```
<input type="radio" name="itemOption" id="deleteAllItems" value="deleteAllItems">Delete items
<input type="radio" name="itemOption" id="moveAllItems" value="moveAllItems" checked>Move items

<select id="inputCategory" name="category" data-dependent='{"itemOption": "moveAllItems"}'>
   <option>Choose a category to move the items to...</option>
   <option>Category A</option>
   <option>Category B</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to replace `$(target)` with `$('[name="'+target+'"]')` :

```js
$('[data-dependent]').each(function () {
    var $ele = $(this);
    var dependsOn = $ele.data('dependent');
    $.each(dependsOn, function (target, value) {  
        $('[name="'+target+'"]').on('change', function () {
            $ele.toggle($(this).val() === value);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="itemOption" id="deleteAllItems" value="deleteAllItems">Delete items
<input type="radio" name="itemOption" id="moveAllItems" value="moveAllItems" checked>Move items

<select id="inputCategory" name="category" data-dependent='{"itemOption": "moveAllItems"}'>
   <option>Choose a category to move the items to...</option>
   <option>Category A</option>
   <option>Category B</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8c2eqbu1/)

```js
// add event listener for this group of radio inputs
$('input[name="itemOption"]').on('change', function(){
    // depending on the "checked" value of #moveAllItems, using a ternary operator set 
    // the css "display" to "inline-block" if it's checked, or "none" if unchecked
    var show = ($('#moveAllItems').is(':checked')) ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
    $('#inputCategory').css({display: show});
})
```

```css
#inputCategory{ display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="itemOption" id="deleteAllItems" value="deleteAllItems" checked>Delete items
<input type="radio" name="itemOption" id="moveAllItems" value="moveAllItems">Move items

<select id="inputCategory" name="category" data-dependent='{"itemOption": "moveAllItems"}'>
   <option>Choose a category to move the items to...</option>
   <option>Category A</option>
   <option>Category B</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can make the `select` element to be hidden using CSS as follows:

```
#inputCategory {
  display: none;
}
```

Then, you can register a `on click` listener on the radio buttons that you want to make the select element to appear (in this case all radio buttons):

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
  $('#inputCategory').show(); // Show element
});
```

See **[working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vh991hga/)**